# Update Xcode Compiler

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction, xcode4, clang

Is there a way to update the built-in Xcode compiler? I'm on Snow Leopard so I'm stuck with Xcode 4.2, which has a pre-3.0 version of Clang. I can build my own Clang that will work from Terminal, but I'd like to update Xcode's version of Clang too. Is that possible?